# Performance monitoring of application

Tags: performance, logging, asp.net-core, monitoring, serilog

I would like to have special performance log with information about 
http request on one line

- requested url
- elapsed time
- username
- returned status code
- activity id (in case that some request will internally redirected to another action)

I am using serilog now for logging unhandled exceptions. Where is ideal place to add this kind of log insertion or what is best practice ? It is good practice to store logs into the database ?

Comment: You should use something like prometheus and a metrics library to measure and track performance

Comment: thank you i will look into that, but i would like to keep things easy. For example my application have only execute permission on the database and i feel i can expect some issue in this way.

Comment: Why downvote ? Should i add some details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it simple and use you own solution you could write a [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) for the asp.net core pipeline to track the required data.

I would not recommend to use Serilog to persist the collected information. Serilog is a logging framework and should not be used to track application metrics.

Use directly a database (sql, mongo, etc.) to store and analyse your data. You have already defined the object model in your question, so it should be easy for you to create and persist an instance of your model in the database.

Comment: Thank you Jehof, i wrote middleware which seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm maintaining a fairly complete "Serilog middleware" example [here](https://github.com/datalust/serilog-middleware-example), with some explanation in [this blog post](https://blog.getseq.net/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/). It targets the one-event-per-request goal, and ships as source so that it's easy to customize the included properties. HTH :-)

Answer (score 3):

The middleware approach seems to work.

```
public class PerformanceMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public PerformanceMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<PerformanceMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            await next.Invoke(context);

            stopwatch.Stop();

            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_insertPerformance", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    // set parameters
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            // We dont want show this error to user.
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in PerformanceMiddleware database operation.");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at an APM tool or tracing tool to do this versus just creating logs with data that do not allow you to actually identify and solve problems. APm tools provide a lot more value beyond just logging performance data, but instead enable you to solve problems. The leaders in this area are AppDynamics, New Relic, and Dynatrace. There are many open source tools which can help here too, such as Zipkin, Jaeger, and Skywalking. You may want to explain the architecture and language of your app too :)

Comment: I wanted to keep it simple. I already log unhandled errors with Serilog, so I am able to get informations about the application errors.

Comment: Yes, unhandled exceptions are certainly one of the ways to debug problems, but there are many other problem categories outside of errors which you may run into that will be difficult to debug in production, for example, performance issues (db, code apis), usage questions, and code efficiency that APM tools can solve. Many of the commercial tools also help with infrastructure monitoring as well.